# Exclude item on orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have 4 item in `ng-repeat`. How can I exclude one item in `orderBy`?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'id':true">

$scope.items = [
    {"name":"item1","id":1},
    {"name":"item2","id":2},
    {"name":"item3","id":3},
    {"name":"item4","id":4}
];
```

How can I make, say, id:3 always appear as the first item?

[**plunker demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAYN0FVtN2OjOKBi3npv?p=preview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a function to alter the value you sort by [(plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7T1YD709eeclSWlPIAb?p=preview):

```
$scope.itemSortValue = function(item) {
  if (item.id == 3)
    return -1;
  return item.id;
}
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:itemSortValue">
  {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: cool man! awesome! what is the different with this kind of function with custom filter?

Comment: A custom filter instead of `orderBy` could do the same thing, you'd just have to do the sorting yourself so passing a function to `orderBy` is a little easier.