# how to put an item on first in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

my html is like

```
 <select id="dpdlanguage" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectlanguages" ng-options="language for language in allLanguages | orderBy:'toString()'" class="form-control tool-features-text"></select>
```

in list I am having language 'English', I want to put 'English' and remaining item alphabetically, how can I do this.
thanks in advance

Comment: You either need to pre-sort your allLanguages list, or provide a custom sorting directive (replacing orderBy)

Comment: you can make use of a custom directive as given in

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557756/exclude-item-on-orderby>

Answer (score 0):

Just use an option in middle

```
<select id="dpdlanguage" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectlanguages" ng-options="language for language in allLanguages | orderBy:'toString()'" class="form-control tool-features-text">
<option value='English'>English</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Won't he just end up with English twice?

Comment: No. Angular do the reset of thing. It's repeat others without English option

Comment: Hadn't seen that before and if that's the case will solve a problem I have!

Comment: No. Angular do the rest of filtering for you !

Answer (score -1):

In controller

```
 $scope.correctlySelected = $scope.options[1];
```

and in the view

```
  <select ng-model="correctlySelected"
            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
        </select>
```

Hi please refer the below fiddle....

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to get English as the first item in his list. Once he has that this will select it!

Comment: yes, I want English at first and remaining alphabetically.

Comment: Try the code which underscore has given and change <option value='English'>English</option> to <option value='English' selected>English</option>